# What Azure permission does a programmer need to run Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2019

I have Visual Studio 2019 installed on an Azure machine and every time I run it, it asks for username and password which I enter.  It then says Elevation is required.  The System Admin grants this but it is only for 15 mins.  What permission do I need to be able to run VS19 without permission or elevation?  Systems Admin doesn't know either.

Comment: is the answer provided by AjayKumarGhose-MT was helpful ? if so could please accept the Answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual Studio as an administrator follow these steps to open the IDE:

NOTE: These instructions are for Windows 10. They are similar for other versions of Windows.

1. Open the  **Start**  menu, and scroll to Visual Studio 2019.
2. From the right-click or context menu of  **Visual Studio 2019**, select  **More**  >  **Run as administrator**.

   When Visual Studio starts,  **(Administrator)**  appears after the product name in the title bar.

You can also modify the application shortcut to always run with administrative permissions:

1. Open the  **Start**  menu, scroll to the version of Visual Studio that you're using, and then select  **More**  >  **Open file location**.
2. In  **File Explorer**, locate the  **Visual Studio**  shortcut for the version that you're using. Then, right-click the shortcut and select  **Send to**  >  **Desktop (create shortcut)**.
3. On the  **Windows**  desktop, right-click the  **Visual Studio**  shortcut, and then select  **Properties**.
4. Select the  **Advanced**  button, and then select the  **Run as administrator**  check box.
5. Select  **OK**, and then select  **OK**  again.

For reference follow  this    [Visual Studio 2019 troubleshoot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/enabling-administrator-updates?view=vs-2019)

Or, When it shows elevation is required ,
Please close the VS Installer and try running it as administrator from start menu.
Or trying to run
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VisualStudio\Installer\vs_installer.exe`  directly.